# Spring - Java EE User still null after authentication

Tags: spring, security, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I'm new to Java EE / Spring and I've been fighting with security for the past two days. I finally have to the point where I can authenticate with Java EE and authorize with Spring. Unfortunately, I can't access the Java EE authentication from Spring to do the authorization.

The general idea for the application is this:

1. If you're not logged in, Spring security redirects you to the login page
2. The login page is the only page that is locked by Java EE. It outputs a form for authentication
3. After successfully logging in, the user is redirected to the home page, which **should** have the authentication object associated with it.

Note the emphasis on **should** since it isn't. For whatever reason, the user is coming back as authenticated but anonymous. If I could simply get the username, I could construct the user details.

Here's the relevant snippets from my `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</filter>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Home Page Only</web-resource-name>
        <description>Rely on Spring for Authorization</description>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginfailed</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

And my security-content.xml for spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/about" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login default-target-url='/index.jsp' 
            always-use-default-target='true' login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
        />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="securityRef"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="securityRef"
        class="my.custom.authprovider.AuthenticationProviderImpl"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Java EE authentication you should configure
PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter (more precisely J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter).
Also, you need to configure J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource to populate a user granted authorities:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#j2ee-preauth-details

BTW, What advantages do you see to use Java EE Form authentication?

*Added after the comment.*

If required to use Java EE authentication your approach should be corrected:  you should protect the whole application by Java EE authentication. 
In this case each request that come to Spring Security will be authenticated by Java EE container and Spring Security can authenticate the request by J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. 
So the corrected flow

1. If a user is not logged in, Java EE container redirects the user to the login page
2. After a successfully authentication, the user is redirected to a page protected by Spring Security. Spring Security can authenticate the request by J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.

Comment: I would rather not use it, honestly, but the application is running on a WAS server which is setup to authenticate using J2EE against an Active Directory.

I tried using J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter previously with a different setup. I'll try using it in this setup and let you know what the results are.